# Partial fractions of $\frac{-5x+19}{(x-1/2)(x+1/3)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Alright, I need to find the partial fractions for the expression above. I have tried writing this as $$\frac{a}{x-1/2}+\frac{b}{x+1/3}$$ but the results give me $a=25.8$ and $b=-20.8$, which are slightly wrong because they give me $5x+19$ instead of $-5x+19$. Can you please help? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format the formulas. Currently they are hard to read.

Comment: You get $a + b = -5$ for the coefficient of $x$, and $a/3 - b/2 = 19$. You simply have a mistake in your computation.

Comment: But I have checked it numerous times T_T

Comment: $a = 99/5$ and $b = -124/5$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Then group the terms with $x$, and the constant terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific type of fractions, there is an easier way - it's my favourite - to find partial fractions. If a given fraction satisfies the following 2 conditions, then it becomes amazingly easy to separate it into partial fractions:

- The degree of numerator is $<$ the degree of denominator
- The denominator can be expressed as a product of linear and non-repeating factors (that is, each factor in the denominator is raised to the power 1)

Your question satisfies these two conditions. So, here's the method: (I'll explain using an example)

Consider $ \dfrac { x - 2 } {(x-7)(x + 8)} $. Now, notice that the denominator vanishes at $ x = 7 $ and $ x = -8 $. So, put $x = 7$ *everywhere but there where the denominator's factor becomes zero*.

That is, write this:
$$ \dfrac {7-2} { (x - 7)(7 + 8) } = \dfrac 5 {15(x-7)} $$

Now substitute $ x = -8$ *everywhere but there where the denominator's factor becomes zero*.

That is, write this:
$$ \dfrac { -8 - 2 } {(-8-7)(x - 8)} = \dfrac {10} {15(x+8)}  $$

So, your answer is the sum of these two terms. That is:

$$ \dfrac { x - 2 } {(x-7)(x + 8)} = \dfrac 5 {15(x-7)} + \dfrac {10} {15(x+8)}  $$

You can check. It works.

So your fraction can be written as:

$$ \dfrac{-5x+19}{(x-1/2)(x+1/3)} = \dfrac { 16.5 } { 5/6(x - 1/2) } - \dfrac { 21.67 } { 1/5(x - 1/3) } $$

Comment: This method is called "Everywhere but there" method!

Answer (score 3):

Either you've started from the wrong equations, or you've made a calculation mistake (don't worry, happens to all of us sometimes). When you write
$$\frac{a}{x-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{b}{x+\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{-5x+19}{(x-\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{1}{3})}$$
you get
$$\frac{a(x+\frac{1}{3})}{(x-\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{1}{3})}+\frac{b(x-\frac{1}{2})}{(x-\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{1}{3})}=\frac{ax+bx+\frac{a}{3}-\frac{b}{2}}{(x-\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{1}{3})}=\frac{-5x+19}{(x-\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{1}{3})}$$
so that the correct equations to solve are
$$\begin{align*}
a+b&=-5\\[0.1in]
\tfrac{a}{3}-\tfrac{b}{2}&=19
\end{align*}$$