# Partial fraction expansion of $\frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, partial-fractions

I try to find a partial fraction expansion of $\dfrac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^n (x+k)}$ (to calculate its integral).
After checking some values of $n$, I noticed that it seems to be true that $\dfrac{n!}{\prod_{k=0}^n (x+k)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^k{n \choose k}}{x+k}$. However, I can't think of a way to prove it. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: See my answer over here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444288/partial-fractions-of-frac-5x19x-1-2x1-3
Doesn't really help you prove what you want to, but it provides a very easy method for "partial-fractionating" such functions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since every $k,\; k=-n,\ldots, 0$ is a simple pole of the given fraction then its decomposition take the form

$$\frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{x+k}$$
and we have
$$a_k=\lim_{x \to -k}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{a_i(x+k)}{x+i} = \lim_{x \to -k} (x+k)\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{a_i}{x+i}$$
$$= \lim_{x \to -k} \frac{x+k}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}=\frac{1}{-k(-k+1)(-k+2)...(-k+n)}=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}$$
so yes it's true that
$$\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k{n\choose k}}{x+k}$$

Comment: Well done, my friend!

Answer (score 12):

Notice that:
$$
\frac{1}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{(x+n) - x}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)} = \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{1}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)} - \frac{1}{(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}\right)
$$

This gives you a recursion formula for partial fraction expansion. You can use it to check your conjecture, and prove it by induction if it's indeed true.

See also this answer: [Series of inverses of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630360/series-of-inverses-of-binomial-coefficients/630361#630361) for another approach.