# Prove that $ \binom nm \sum_{i=0}^{m} (-1)^i\frac{\binom mi}{n-m+1+i}=\frac{1}{1+n}$

Tags: combinations

I want to prove that
$$
\binom nm \sum_{i=0}^{m} (-1)^i\frac{\binom mi}{n-m+1+i}=\frac{1}{1+n}\\
$$
$$
\binom nm [ \frac{\binom m0}{n-m+1} +(-1)^1\frac{\binom m1}{n-m+2}+...
..+(-1)^m\frac{\binom mm}{n+1}] 
=\frac{1}{1+n}\\
$$

1. Assume that $m=1$,then it's equal to $1/(n+1)$.
   $$
   \binom n1 [ \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+1}] =\frac{1}{1+n}\\
   $$
2. Assume that $m=2$,then it's equal to $1/(n+1)$.

$$
\binom n2 [ \frac{1}{n-1} -\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}] =\frac{1}{1+n}\\
$$

How to prove that for $\forall m$, this formula is equal to $1/(n+1)$？

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: @Patricio Yeah, I try to use  $(1-1)^m=\binom m0-\binom m1+....\binom mm=0$ to induct, but I failed. It's so complexed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial fraction expansion of
$$\frac1{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}$$
is
$$\frac1{m!}\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^i\frac{\binom mi}{x+i}.$$
Now take $x=n-m+1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715706/partial-fraction-expansion-of-frac1xx1x2-cdotsxn/715718

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38623/how-to-prove-sum-limits-r-0n-frac-1rr1-binomnr-frac1n1

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that
$$x^{n-m}(1-x)^m=\sum_{i=0}^{m} (-1)^i \binom mi x^{n-m+i}$$
Now integrate with respect to $x$ over the interval $[0,1]$ and recall the definition of [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).